# Can I check the type of the keys/values of an Array of Pairs?

Tags: raku

I need to create a data structure with keys/values which maintains the order. The hashes don't keep the order, so I'm using an array of pairs. All is working as expected. However, I would like to check the types of the each pair before of adding it to the array. The pair should be always Str => Int.

```
[0] >  my Pair @list
[1] >  @list.push: "Roma" => 1                                                 
[Roma => 1]
[2] >  @list.push: "Paris" => 2                                                
[Roma => 1 Paris => 2]
[3] >  @list.push: "Lisboa" => 3                                               
[Roma => 1 Paris => 2 Lisboa => 3]
```

I'm looking for something similar to `my Int %list{Str}`. Any idea?.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's not a syntactic shortcut for it, but you can do it by declaring a `subset` type that constrains the `key` and `value` of the `Pair` as follows:

```
[0] > subset PairStrInt of Pair where .key ~~ Str && .value ~~ Int;
(PairStrInt)
[1] > my PairStrInt @list;
[]
[2] > @list.push: "Roma" => 1
[Roma => 1]
[3] > @list.push: "Paris" => "2"           
Type check failed for an element of @list; expected PairStrInt but got Pair (:Paris("2"))
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

Comment: My intuition about what the code is doing, plus some crude tests to sanity test, suggest to me that changing the `where` clause to `:(Str :$key, Int :$value)` (which is a [signature](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature) doing object destructuring of a `Pair` object) typically will, or at least might, perform faster than `.key ~~ Str && .value ~~ Int`.